# How to use another project namespace?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to include a namespace from another project in my project but I get the "symbol could not be resolved" error.

```
using namespace project;
```

^ This line gives the "symbol could not be resolved" error. 
I have the files with this namespace included in my project. 
I'm using eclipse on ubuntu Mate.

Comment: Did you include any header from the other project (directly or indirectly) before that line?

Comment: Strongly recommend adding a [mcve] because all we can do for you with what you have provided is guess and provide pithy little comments like this one.

Comment: Think carefully about whether you actually need to use `using namespace ...;`. Is the convenience of typing `foo` vs. `project::foo` worth it when you now have to worry about namespace clashes? Can you just `using project::foo;` instead if it's used repeeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

The C++ compiler does not know about the project management of your IDE (development environment).

It only sees the source code itself. If you add an `#include` statement the compiler will also see the included code as if it has been put at that place. `#include` is recursive, so if one included file includes another that will be seen as well.

The error message means that at the point of your `using namespace project` the symbol `project` is not known. So, you obviously miss an earlier `#include` statement including any header of the other project which contains a `namespace project { ... }` defining the namespace.

Any implementation (`.cpp`) file using namespace `project` needs such an `#include` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As [bjhend's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393672/5595995), you may need put the header file in header.

Here are three files as example:

main.cpp

```
// Call namespace in "project.hpp"
#import project.hpp

using namespace project;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  // will print out "Benjamin" in "project.hpp" file
  std::cout << name << std::endl;

  // will print out same "Benjamin" using the function in 
  // "project.cpp" file, and "John" in the function. 
  show();

  return 0;
}
```

project.hpp

```
namespace project {
  string name = "Benjamin";
}

// Declare function
void show();
```

project.cpp

```
// Call namespace in "project.hpp"
#import project.hpp 

// Define function that declared in "project.hpp" 
void show () {
   string name = "John";
   std::cout << project::name << std::endl;
   std::cout << name << std::endl;

}
```

I have seen several suggestions of avoiding `using namespace`. You may consider using `project::` instead of `using namespace project`.

Answer (score -3):

To use a namespace of another project, u have to refer that project in your existing project.

In eclipse, you can add the project by following below steps.

1. Right click > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols
2. Go to Tab Library and Add new library path
3. You can see the referenced path, check the project and Apply.
4. You can now use the namespace.

[This Link](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_ref.htm) can give more info about references and other settings of the project in eclipse.

Comment: Very thin answer. Effectively link only. You can salvage this answer by summarizing the contents of the link to prevent this answer from becoming completely useless when the link rots.

Comment: Oops. my bad, i should have explained.